# Rotating a view with CGAffineTransform only works once?

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I have a custom view that I want to rotate 90 degrees every 3 seconds, and below is the code I'm using

```
private func _rotateSelf(duration: Double = 1.0, delay: Double = 3.0) {
    print("self._rotateSelf() called from UICustomView")
    
    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: delay, options: [.curveEaseInOut], animations: {
        // TODO: this only works on the first function call
        self.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity.rotated(by: (.pi / 2))
    }, completion: { finished in
        if finished == true {
            print("Animation finished")
            self._rotateSelf()
        }
    })
}
```

The problem is that the animation only works when the function is called the first time. With each call after that, no animation happens, and function just gets called over and over again, eventually freezing up the app.

What am I not understanding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not rotating an additional 90º each time. You are only setting a 90º total rotation. Instead of applying a rotation to the `identity` transform, rotate the view's current transform.

```
self.transform = self.transform.rotated(by: .pi / 2)
```